# How to Embed .exe to run before ClickOnce setup.exe

Tags: wpf, clickonce

i need to know how can i embed an exe (for example to check prerequiesties must be installed beore the application installation) before the ClickOne setup.exe which i created for my application to be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no need to do that. ClickOnce can take care of any required prerequisites for you. If you open the startup project's setting page (right click on the project in the Solution Exlorer and select 'Properties', or press Alt+Enter) in Visual Studio, you'll see a number of vertical tabs on the left hand side of the properties window. You can set up your required prerequisites by clicking on the `prerequisites` button on the 'Publish' tab.

---

UPDATE >>>

When your users install a click once application, they are shown a web page with a section like this on it:

[image]

If they click the `Install` button, they install *all* of the prerequisites and if they click the `launch` link, then they can just install the application.

For more information, please read through the [ClickOnce Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page on MSDN. Further MSDN resources include:

> [How to: Include Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873130.aspx)
>   [How to: Install Prerequisites with a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8st7th1x.aspx)

Comment: thanks alot for your reply , but there is still one thing i couldn't understand that the exes i added in the prerequisites will not be run automatically when i start the setup of my application?? should i run them manually each time?? i need them to be run automatically as the user that will setup the application will not get the prerequisites setup point :)

Comment: And what  can i do to make ana exe (for application is done by me) to run before the setup rather than the ones on the list in the prerequisites screen like Windows installer 4.5 ... etc ???

Comment: If you want to find out something about Microsoft, it's best to look on MSDN: Try [Walkthrough: Creating a Custom Installer for a ClickOnce Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx).